# Finding correlation between orders (DV) and price (IV), with many other IVs at play

Tags: correlation, econometrics

I have a large data set of several million customer orders for a product, over the past two years.  Orders have grown steadily over that period (with periodic swings due to seasonality or other factors), thanks to a combination of organic growth (e.g. word of mouth), and paid marketing.

The price of this product changes semi-regularly — usually up or down \$1-4, off an average price of \$5-6.  Not surprisingly, order volume generally decreases when price goes up, and increases when it goes down.

My goal is to quantify the average impact that an X% increase or decrease in price (independent variable) has on order volume (dependent variable) in a given period (day/week/month), either in terms of raw # of orders, or % increase in orders from the prior period.  My question is how to go about this, in a way that isolates/removes/takes into account all the other independent variables affecting order volume (natural organic growth, marketing campaigns, seasonal swings, etc)?  When finished, I would like the ability to make a statement like “if we lower prices by \$1.00 (or 25%), we should expect an [15%] increase in order volume, on average.”

Given the size of my data set, it would seem a statistical approach/model must exist to help answer this kind of question.  For simplicity’s sake, it’s fine to assume a linear relationship between price and order volume (i.e. if a 20% price increase leads to 15% lower order volume, then a 40% price increase would cause a 30% drop in order volume).  Getting an answer that is “directionally” accurate is much better than nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have very little background in statistics and no experience with statistics software packages, so even keywords to Google search and set me on the right path of discovery are better than nothing.  Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: When you write IV do you mean Instrumental Variables?

Comment: My advice would be to check the Log-log model, and interpretations for the coefficients. Also, be carefull when adding dummy variables to this model. The dummy may not be in a log. Or you could try a log-linear model.